# Nivo slider wont hide previous image

Tags: javascript, html, css, nivo-slider

```
http://74.52.155.226/~projtest/team/harmeet/emed/
```

This is the link of the project i am working on. Now the slider i have used is nivo and the images in it will be png. I tried looking for an option into the js itself but i couldn't find any option. The issue is that when the next image loads, the previous image is still displayed whereas the behaviour should be that the previous image fades out and next image fades in. Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of jQuery. I think it is 1.8.3. That often helps issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting it to use the 'fade' style?

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'fade'
});
```

Full usage details available on this page:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

Comment: I have already set that option in the nivo js itself. But still if i do as you mentioned here, nothing happens and the problem remains the same.